# Перенос настроек сетевой карты

Tags: windows

Здравствуйте.

Есть две рабочие станции с одинаково зеркальным железом и предустановленными

Windows 10 OEM версиями лицензионными.

В настройках сетевой карты более 30 параметров.

**Вопрос**
1) Есть какие-либо инструменты от Microsoft для переноса настроек сетевой карты?
(с одной станции на другую)

2) Есть какие-либо инструменты от других производителей для переноса настроек сетевой карты? (с одной станции на другую)

Заранее, спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 0):

Что касается стека протоколов IP, то дублирование конфигурации производится утилитой netsh. Например:

```
netsh interface dump
```

Вывод в файл, соответственно:

```
netsh interface dump>config.txt
```

Что касается переноса конфигурации драйвера, естественно, нужно обращаться к производителю.